# Why does shorthand for asynchronous functions work without having async or await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

When writing async functions, usually if you do not explicitly writer `await` or `async` your compiler would throw an error or warning. Example of correct syntax below:

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetEntitiesAsync() =>
            await TEntityRepository.GetAllAsync();
```

Now the following works still, it is async and returns a Task<List>

```
public Task<List<TEntity>> GetEntitiesAsync() =>
            TEntityRepository.GetAllAsync();
```

Why does the second one still work

Comment: The method `GetEntitiesAsync` is defined as returning a `Task<List<Entity>>`. The method `GetAllAsync` presumably also returns a `Task<List<Entity>>` - so why wouldn't it work? It's just a totally normal, bog-standard method at that point - it works for the same reason `public int GetNumber() => 42` works...

Comment: in fact if you only have one await and it also is the return value then code analyzer will complain; it's not necessary to use async/await in that case. So in this case, 2 is preferred

Comment: This needs to be closed as a duplicate. for reference https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html Also note, removing the await has differences and can potentially cause issues unless you know what you are doing and/or its a simple task forward

Comment: Regarding my earlier note the async fixer package speaks of this. https://github.com/semihokur/AsyncFixer . see AsyncFixer01. If you use disassembly tools you'll see the difference under the hood. It does come at a cost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both calls return the same Task, so they are the effectively the same.

In order to use "await" in a method, that method MUST be labeled async.  Since the second one doesn't use await, it doesn't need to be labeled async.

That's it.

With that said, it probably isn't a good ideas to do this as there are some pitfalls as described in the article mentioned by @TheGeneral:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html